# Dovecot Sieve doesn't move spam to Junk folder in maildir

Tags: dovecot, maildir, sieve

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 mail server with **postfix/spamassassin/dovecot** with virtual mailboxes in **maildir** format. The whole process is working excellently since a year. **Spams are marked** with "*****SPAM*****" in subject and with "X-Spam-Flag: YES" in email header.

I tried now to add **sieve** to dovecot to move the SPAM messages into the Junk folder without any success, I don't see any sign that **sieve** does something at all.

My dovecot.conf:

```
auth_mechanisms = cram-md5
auth_verbose = yes
base_dir = /var/run/dovecot/
info_log_path = /var/log/dovecot.info
log_path = /var/log/dovecot
log_timestamp = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S "
mail_location = maildir:/home/vmail/%d/%n
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/passwd
  driver = passwd-file
}
protocols = imap pop3
service auth {
  executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/auth
  user = root
}
service imap-login {
  chroot = login
  executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/imap-login
  user = dovecot
  # disable non secure IMAP
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 0
  }
}
service imap {
  executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/imap
}
service pop3-login {
  chroot = login
  executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3-login
  user = dovecot
  # disable pop3
  inet_listener pop3 {
    port = 0
  }
  inet_listener pop3s {
    port = 0
  }
}
service pop3 {
  executable = /usr/lib/dovecot/pop3
}
ssl = no
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/users
  driver = passwd-file
}
valid_chroot_dirs = /var/spool/vmail
protocol pop3 {
  pop3_uidl_format = %08Xu%08Xv
}

# SSL settings
ssl = yes
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem

# SMTP authentication
service auth {
  # Postfix smtp-auth
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
    group = postfix
  }
}

# Default separator definition needed by doveadm for migration
namespace {
  inbox = yes
  separator = /
}

plugin {
  sieve = /etc/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve
}
protocol lda {
  mail_plugins = $mail_plugins sieve
}
```

I've added only **plugin** and **protocol lda** now. The content of the file *default.sieve*:

```
require "fileinto";
if header :contains "X-Spam-Flag" "YES" {
    fileinto "Junk";
}
```

The test SPAM message is marked as SPAM, but not moved to the folder Junk. I don't see anything in *mail.log* that is associated to sieve.:

```
Jul 30 20:05:12 zg-3 postfix/smtpd[4446]: connect from smtp4.enternet.hu[62.112.192.37] 
Jul 30 20:05:13 zg-3 postfix/smtpd[4446]: 3C4CC9F570: client=smtp4.enternet.hu[62.112.192.37] 
Jul 30 20:05:13 zg-3 postfix/cleanup[4450]: 3C4CC9F570: message-id=<c6b3bca5-ece3-9e69-8e30-28173abc2ec6@hu.inter.net> 
Jul 30 20:05:13 zg-3 postfix/qmgr[1557]: 3C4CC9F570: from=<nagyt@hu.inter.net>, size=918, nrcpt=1 (queue active) 
Jul 30 20:05:13 zg-3 postfix/smtpd[4446]: disconnect from smtp4.enternet.hu[62.112.192.37] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=7 
Jul 30 20:05:13 zg-3 postfix/pickup[3949]: 5F7FEA3CBC: uid=1003 from=<nagyt@hu.inter.net> 
Jul 30 20:05:13 zg-3 postfix/pipe[4451]: 3C4CC9F570: to=<tibor@softxs.ch>, relay=spamassassin, delay=0.15, delays=0.05/0.01/0/0.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via spamassassin service) 
Jul 30 20:05:13 zg-3 postfix/qmgr[1557]: 3C4CC9F570: removed 
Jul 30 20:05:13 zg-3 postfix/cleanup[4450]: 5F7FEA3CBC: message-id=<c6b3bca5-ece3-9e69-8e30-28173abc2ec6@hu.inter.net> 
Jul 30 20:05:13 zg-3 postfix/qmgr[1557]: 5F7FEA3CBC: from=<nagyt@hu.inter.net>, size=3304, nrcpt=1 (queue active) 
Jul 30 20:05:13 zg-3 postfix/virtual[4455]: 5F7FEA3CBC: to=<tibor@softxs.ch>, relay=virtual, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir) 
Jul 30 20:05:13 zg-3 postfix/qmgr[1557]: 5F7FEA3CBC: removed
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The problem was, that Postfix was not configured to deliver via dovecot's LDA, thus sieve never gets called.

The appropriate configuration lines in postfix/master.cf

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter=spamassassin
[...]
### Configuration for dovecot as LDA (New 2019-08-13)
# spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${original_recipient}
spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DROhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e
  /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop}
dovecot unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop}
```

The appropriate configuration lines in postfix/main.cf:

```
### Configuration for dovecot as LDA (New 2019-08-13)
virtual_transport = dovecot
spamassassin_destination_recipient_limit = 1
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
```

The files *dovecot.cnf* and *sieve/default.sieve* are the same as in the question.

It is worth to check */var/log/dovecot.info* beside */var/log/mail.log*. A similar line should appear on junk mail:

```
2019-08-13 15:52:15 lda(tibor.nagy@softxs.ch): Info: sieve: msgid=<904f3c82-6db1-8b5c-d465-ef140c2f5948@hu.inter.net>: stored mail into mailbox 'Junk'
```